# "Unable to start debugging" message in VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have this message when I start debug in VS 2008:

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start debugging

Because of this I cannot debug any programs any more. Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: I think you'll need to supply more information on the project you're trying to debug and possibly even some code. Is is just this project that's affected or all projects?

Comment: I want a massage during debugging too!

Comment: @Thomas: damn, thats what I wanted to write too :-)

Comment: Well Marc's edit has clarified my one project/all projects question, but knowing what types of project (winforms, wpf, web) are affected would be a great help

Comment: I have the same problem, and it has nothing do do with the code. Its the program itself. I'm using Visual Studio Developer 2008. For me, it's web projects. F5 is not working.

Comment: This is caused by a lot of things, but it all boils down to a miscommunication between VS and Windows. What version of Windows/IIS are you running?

Comment: I just bought a new computer and installed Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition and am now having this bloody problem! EXACT same problem! Google has yielded no help

Comment: I'm assuming he/she's just trying to create a standard Windows Forms application and debug that... Can somebody please provide more suggestions/answers to this as I just bought a new computer and am having the exact same problem. Exact same error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I brought my code over from another machine. I kept getting that message when trying to debug until I completely cleaned out the output directory (I just manually deleted everything in it). Once I did that, I could run in debug mode.

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I had built my app with VS 2010. Then switched back to VS 2008.  Both slns build to the same output directory (probably not a great idea!) and trying to build VS 2008 after VS 2010 was causing this problem.  A clean rebuild didn't help, I had to delete all my output directories then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it means the URL you have setup for the project in the Project Properties doesn't match what it is in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a client app and not a web app, there are a few things to try:

1. Make sure you run Visual Studio as an admin (elevated).
2. Make sure you have cleanly built your project and have matching symbols (.pdb and .exe have same timestamp).
3. Make sure you are not already debugging the app with VS or a different debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible when in VS->Server Explorer Application debugging is enabled or CLR/SQL debugging is enabled..

Disabling that might solve the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are a member of the Administrators group and the Debugger Users group on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error after our sys admins pushed new security settings. Added the ASP user to the Administrators group and that resolved it.